# How to unit test Visual Basic 6 legacy code?

Tags: testing, quality, legacy, visual-basic-6

I am doing legacy software programming in Visual Basic 6.0.

How do I unit test it?

Answer (score 5):

Does your IDE support unit testing? If not, you can always create your own unit test framework in any programming language by creating assertion methods `Assert.AreEqual`, `Assert.IsTrue`, etc. and designing a custom build which runs them on every build.

You can also use [one of the multiple unit test frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#Visual_Basic_.28VB6.29) for Visual Basic 6.

Comment: Use one of the existing unit testing frameworks. Don't bother writing your own.

Answer (score 3):

Googling for "visual basic unit test" lead me to the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks) on unit testing in all kinds of languages. Somewhere down the list is [a table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#Visual_Basic_.28VB6.29) with tools for unit testing VB6 code. That should get you started.

Comment: +1 for "how to fish". I've had several times where I just typed the wrong terms into the search engine...